# Why we use validation set (not train or test set) in early stopping function ( DL / CNN )?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

This is my first attempt to CNN in Pytorch. I have gone by few tutorials, but still need some clarification.

I have theoretical question, I don't understand why in **early stopping function** we base on **validation set**, not train or test set?

Has it something common with metrics we got from validation set?

Comment: Perhaps see https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/16/what-is-early-stopping-in-machine-learning

Answer (score 1):

The number of training epochs is one of the *training* hyper-parameters. Therefore, you MUST NOT use the test data to determine the value of this hyper-parameter.
Additionally, you cannot use the training set itself to determine the value of early stopping. Therefore, you need to use the validation set for determining this value.